# Dynamic Programming Example and Issue

Tags: vba, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm trying to run a dynamic programming example using VBA that should limit the amount of times the function is recursively called by storing values in a dictionary.

The problem I'm running into is the function is recursively called before the value can be stored in the dictionary with its generated key. Typically, I would use the 'return' keyword after the dictionary key stored the associated value, but that doesn't seem to work in VBA.

```
Public Function count_sets_dp(arr, total)
Dim mem As Dictionary
Set mem = New Dictionary
count_sets_dp = dp(arr, total, GetArrLength(arr), mem)
```

The final 'else' clause initiates the recursion call without storing the result in mem(key).

```
Public Function dp(arr, total, i, mem)
'dynamic programming or memoized solution

Dim Key As String
Dim to_return As Integer

Key = CStr(total) & ":" & CStr(i)
If mem.Exists(Key) Then
      dp = mem(Key)
End If
If total = 0 Then
dp = 1


ElseIf total < 0 Then
dp = 0


ElseIf i < 1 Then
dp = 0


ElseIf total < arr(i) Then
to_return = dp(arr, total, i - 1, mem)

Else: to_return = (dp(arr, total - arr(i), i - 1, mem) + dp(arr, total, i - 1, mem))
mem(Key) = to_return
dp = to_return
End If

End Function
```

It seems like I am not benefitting from the dynamic programming solution here, and I am trying to understand if I have a syntax problem...

````
Sub mysub()

Dim timetaken As Double
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim result As Integer

myArray = [{2,4,6,4,10,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}]

result = count_sets_dp(myArray, 16)

MsgBox (result)

End Sub```
````

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your code is intended to *do* ?

Comment: You can a) add 'Exit Function` in the first `If` block or b) remove `End if` and replace the next `If` with `ElseIf` to get advantage of memorised solutions. Also `ElseIf total < arr(i) Then` does not have any assignment to `dp` so the code will produce incorrect results. @TimWilliams it is an attempt to implement count of subsets of a set with a given sum.

Comment: @BrakNicku I think I may be misunderstanding the benefit of the memoized solution. My expectation was that I could include many more 4's in the array, and it wouldn't increase the processing time by much b/c the result would already be stored in the dictionary. When I implement, I can only add two more 4's to the array before I get an overflow error when compared to a recursive solution that doesn't use memorization. Is this typical?

Comment: You have to change `Integer` to `Long` to get rid of integer overflow, but once you change your code like I said above it should perform well.

Comment: Thank you. As for your comment on 'no assignment to dp' - is it not possible to assign temporarily to a placeholder variable (to_return), and return after performing some other desired action?

Comment: I ended up getting rid of the to_return variable and provided an assignment to dp for each condition. moved mem(key) = dp outside of if block. I think this is the most efficient. I can step through an array with 10 values in about 30 seconds, compared to 150 seconds using strictly a recursive solution.

Comment: Both changes - removing redundant `to_return` variable and making sure each partial solution gets saved are improving the code. Not quite sure how you got those 30s vs 150s timings, 10 element array should be calculated in a fraction of a second even with the recursive only algorithm. Best way to compare both methods is to add a variable to count how many time `dp` has been called with/without saving partial solutions. PS use @ to make sure user gets notified about your response.

Comment: @BrakNicku I held F8 (step-through debug mode) and timed with a stopwatch to determine approximately how long it takes to execute both functions. Thx for the tip about the function call counter - that's a much more scalable solution.